# How to sign a meta-transaction using ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, signature, meta-transactions, eip712

I am trying to sign a meta-transaction so I can execute a function from a smart contract with 1 account but pay for gas fees with another.

This is the code I have (this works when using `MetaMask` in a front-end, but now I want to do it in a `node.js` application using `ethers`):

```
const config = require("../config/config");
const ethers = require('ethers');
const MinimalForwarder = require("../util/abis/MinimalForwarder.json");
const GameEvents = require("../util/abis/GameEvents.json");
const networkRpcURL = config.web3.networkRpcUrl;
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(networkRpcURL);
const { signTypedMessage } = require('eth-sig-util');

const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
];

const ForwardRequest = [
  { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
];

const getMetaTxTypeData = (chainId, verifyingContract) => {
  return {
    types: {
      EIP712Domain,
      ForwardRequest,
    },
    domain: {
      name: 'MinimalForwarder',
      version: '0.0.1',
      chainId,
      verifyingContract,
    },
    primaryType: 'ForwardRequest',
  }
};

const createInstance = (address, abi) => {
  return new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
}

const getSigner = (i) => {

  // Use the mnemonic to create an HDNode instance
  const account = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(config.web3.mnemonic).derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/" + i);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account, provider);

  return signer;

};

const sendMetaTx = async (iterator, userAddress, sessionId, sessionType) => {

  const url = config.web3.webhookUrl;
  if (!url) throw new Error(`Missing relayer url`);

  const forwarder = createInstance(config.web3.minimalForwarder, MinimalForwarder.abi);
  const gameEvents = createInstance(config.web3.gameEvents, GameEvents.abi);
  const signer = await getSigner(iterator);
  const from = await signer.getAddress();
  const data = gameEvents.interface.encodeFunctionData('startGameSession', [userAddress, sessionId, sessionType]);
  const to = gameEvents.address;
  const request = await signMetaTxRequest(signer.provider, forwarder, { to, from, data });

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(request),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });

}

const signMetaTxRequest = async (signer, forwarder, input) => {
  const request = await buildRequest(signer, input);
  const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
  const signature = await signTypedData(signer, input.from, toSign);
  return { type: 'forward', forwarderAddress: forwarder.address, signature, request };
}

const buildRequest = async (provider, input) => {
  let nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(input.from);
  nonce = nonce.toString();
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}

const buildTypedData = async (forwarder, request) => {
  const chainId = await forwarder.provider.getNetwork().then((n) => n.chainId);
  const typeData = getMetaTxTypeData(chainId, forwarder.address);
  return { ...typeData, message: request };
}

const signTypedData = async (signer, from, data) => {
  // If signer is a private key, use it to sign
  if (typeof(signer) === 'string') {
    const privateKey = Buffer.from(signer.replace(/^0x/, ''), 'hex');
    return signTypedMessage(privateKey, { data });
  }

  // Otherwise, send the signTypedData RPC call
  // Note that hardhatvm and metamask require different EIP712 input
  const isHardhat = data.domain.chainId == 31337;
  const [method, argData] = isHardhat
    ? ['eth_signTypedData', data]
    : ['eth_signTypedData_v4', JSON.stringify(data)]
  return await signer.send(method, [from, argData]);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 46,
    "error": {
        "code": -32601,
        "message": "The method eth_signTypedData_v4 does not exist/is not available"
    }
}
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you sign a message using `ethers` is with function `_signTypedData`, like this:

```
await signer._signTypedData(data.domain, newTypes, data.message);
```

Keep in mind that you don't need `EIP712Domain` in your types, as that is already assumed by `ethers`.

This is a working example of a message signed with this function:

```
const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
];

const ForwardRequest = [
  { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
];

const getMetaTxTypeData = (chainId, verifyingContract) => {
  return {
    types: {
      EIP712Domain,
      ForwardRequest,
    },
    domain: {
      name: 'MinimalForwarder',
      version: '0.0.1',
      chainId,
      verifyingContract,
    },
    primaryType: 'ForwardRequest',
  }
};

const createInstance = (address, abi) => {
  return new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
}

const getSigner = (i) => {
  const account = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(config.web3.mnemonic).derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/" + i);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account, provider);
  return signer;
};

const sendMetaTx = async (iterator, userAddress, sessionId, sessionType) => {

  const url = config.web3.webhookUrl;
  if (!url) throw new Error(`Missing relayer url`);

  const forwarder = createInstance(config.web3.minimalForwarder, MinimalForwarder.abi);
  const gameEvents = createInstance(config.web3.gameEvents, GameEvents.abi);
  const signer = await getSigner(iterator);
  const from = await signer.getAddress();
  const data = gameEvents.interface.encodeFunctionData('startGameSession', [userAddress, sessionId, sessionType]);
  const to = gameEvents.address;
  const request = await signMetaTxRequest(signer, forwarder, { to, from, data });

  return await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(request),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });

}

const signMetaTxRequest = async (signer, forwarder, input) => {
  const request = await buildRequest(forwarder, input);
  const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
  const signature = await signTypedData(signer, toSign);
  return { type: 'forward', forwarderAddress: forwarder.address, signature, request };
}

const buildRequest = async (forwarder, input) => {
  const nonce = await forwarder.getNonce(input.from);
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}

const buildTypedData = async (forwarder, request) => {
  const chainId = await forwarder.provider.getNetwork().then((n) => n.chainId);
  const typeData = getMetaTxTypeData(chainId, forwarder.address);
  return { ...typeData, message: request };
}

const signTypedData = async (signer, data) => {
  const newTypes = {
    ForwardRequest: data.types.ForwardRequest
  }
  return await signer._signTypedData(data.domain, newTypes, data.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using similar code to you and trying to use OpenZeppelin's code. I'm also sending my transaction to an action webhook and was wondering if you had the code for the webhook still.

I was following this guide but there were too many errors with it
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/v2/guide/meta-tx

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting? You should use that code there and `v2` of Defender. The example I have is for `v1`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/97650)